# Truth Question = Only God Knows

Tags: discussion

Many here seem to dislike the term "truth question;" likely because it leaves a bad taste in the mouth to say something that could be interpreted to claim that a site about Christianity is not interested in the truth.

Every "truth question" here does actually have an answer that all (or at least most) of us can agree on: only God truly knows the answer. Everybody else thinks they know.

Instead of telling people we closed their question as off-topic because it is a truth or opinion-based question, would it be better to say something like:  "We all have our ideas, but unless and until God creates an account we just cannot answer this question -- if you can edit it to ask for an answer from a specific group or theologian, we may be able to find an answer for you."

Comment: I personally have taken to calling them "primarily opinion-based", 'cause that's what they really are.

Comment: And I VTC them as too broad because to me, that's what they are.  I don't think they're opinion based of they're looking for the truth. But, I personally think they're only going to find the truth if they scope their questions with [tag:catholicism] ymmv.

Answer (score 2):

"Was Mary a prostitute?" - This is a truth seeking question and not one that is answerable without some debate.  You can answer "probably" and the bible gives hints to **a** Mary being a prostitute.  Similarly, "Was Mary a virgin?"... the list goes on and on.  These questions have little to do Christianity or the study of Christianity as much as they are questions seeking to prove or disprove a fact with historical information.  The questions can be changed and defined into a context to make them good questions - such as, "What passages in the Bible support the Catholic belief that Mary was a virgin?"

I would feel that an answer such as "We all have our ideas, but unless and until God creates an account..." would be more condescending than to simply say that the question is a truth seeking question.  Besides, I am not holding my breath on God creating an account here, so why suggest it?

Comment: I believe that when God does come, he's going to say, "When will you guys get it?  I walked with you in the garden and you didn't listen.  I empowered Moses and you guys didn't listen.  I sent my ONLY SON and you guys STILL didn't get it.  I'm coming down there ONE MORE TIME, open your ears!"